# Detect touch Cocos2d-x

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2d-x and trying to detect touches in my HelloWorld project. Though I'm having no luck.

.h

```
class HelloWorld : public CCLayer{

private:
    CCSpriteBatchNode * _batchNode;
    CCSprite *_turkey;
    virtual void ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
```

.ccp

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    CCLog("this");
}
```

but the thing is that when I click the screen 'this' never shows up in the log. What am i missing here?

thanks!

Edit,

Im using this tutorial. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/11338/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-space-game

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to register with CCTouchDispatcher in order to receive touches:

Write this in your `init()` method in order to receive touches:

```
CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 0);
```

Also I recommend you to receive touch event via targeted touch delegate methods:

```
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchCancelled(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

In order these methods to be called you have to register with touch dispatcher a bit different:

```
CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
```

**EDIT**

In new cocos version `CCTouchDispatcher` is located in `CCDirector`:

It should look something like this:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
```

Comment: hmmm i get the error `No memeber named 'sharedDispatcher'` in 'cocos2d::CCTouchDispatcher' when i ad it to my init(), in HelloWorld.cpp

Comment: @JamesDunay: what cocos version do you use?

Comment: So now i get the error, `Assertion failed: (false), function ccTouchBegan, file /Iphone/SDK/Eyes/Eyes C++/Eyes C++/libs/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.cpp, line 292.`

Comment: I posted the tutorial that I'm using and it doesnt seem to mention any  `getTouchDispatcher` or `CCTouchDispatcher`, but i am able to Log results in his method

Comment: Are you responsible for removing the targeted delegate when the layer is removed?

Answer (score 8):

So something super simple, just added

`this->setIsTouchEnabled(true);`

to my init(); function.

Answer (score 2):

```
'this' never shows up in the log
```

*hints* You might be using a different version of Cocos2D library. Please go to `cocos2d.h` on your project and confirm. (the sample was written on 1.0.1). If you are on a different version, (*guessing*) you might have to use different `ccTouchesBegan` signature and/or fix more than just `setIsTouchEnabled` to make it work. I just downloaded the sample, and the `ccTouchesBegan` call works perfect - without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

`this->setTouchEnabled(true);` works better than `CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);`unfortunately my ccTouchMoved is not picking anything up... :(

Answer (score 0):

for cocos2d-x v3.0..

write this in your '.h' file

```
{bool onTouchBegan (cocos2d::Touch * touch, cocos2d::Event * event);}
```

write this in your '`init()' function`..

```
{
auto listner = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

listner->setSwallowTouches(true);    

listner->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(Gameplay::onTouchBegan, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listner, this);
}
```

and write this in '.cpp' file..

```
bool "YOURCLASSNAME"::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2dEvent* event)
{   
        CCLOG("this");
             return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in below method I am applying touch on Sprite , If you want to apply touch event on TextField , Node , Background , or in any component just Pass that ComponentType into this method and It will work ....

OK LETS BEGIN!!!!

```
void YourClassName::YourListnerMethodName(cocos2d::Sprite* object)
{
   auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
   listener->setSwallowTouches(false);

    listener->onTouchBegan = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
    {
       auto target = event->getCurrentTarget();
       Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());

       // Suppose your sprite or any component is inside in any parent object then use this line instead of above line ... 
       //just uncomment below line and it will work fine in this case   
       //Point locationInNode = target->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());

        if (target->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(locationInNode)) {

           // CODE FOR RESPONSE AFTER TOUCH

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, object);
}
```

Here the target is your component , where you want to apply touch on it

Just don't forget to call this method from ctor or anywhere according to your requirement